# JTable How to add a row between rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've been looking for this quite a long time before and I can't find any question about this nor topic, I am assuming it might be impossible to do, though it seems odd as the feature would be useful.

I would like in the situation when I have let's say 3 rows, to add another one not at the end, but after row number 1. Is that possible in any way?

Please do not mention row arranging based on some id, as that is the last thing I would do in my situation.

Comment: You need to post the code that you have already tried

Comment: Yes it's possible, all depends of what `TableModel` are you using.

Comment: I have no code of adding anything between rows as I simply did not know where to start from, I only do   'model.addRow( new Object[] {"","","","","","","","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0", "0"});'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) <- see docs more contructors

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefualtTableModel(String colNames, int rows);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Then you can use one of the following methods

- [`DefaultTableModel#insertRow(int row, Object[] rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#insertRow%28int,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) - Inserts a row at row in the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.

Or

- [`DefaultTableModel#insertRow(int row, Vector rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#insertRow%28int,%20java.util.Vector%29) - Inserts a row at row in the model. The new row will contain null values unless rowData is specified. Notification of the row being added will be generated.

---